# Hyperledger Fabric 0.6 setup error on make peer or make Step 2/5 error

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

Trying to run make and make peer to setup fabric 0.6
[this link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/8d277a63-4204-4fd3-8cb8-b7cb222cd522/entry/Steps_to_setup_Blockchain_Hyperledger_Fabric_0_6_development_environment_on_Ubuntu?lang=en)

With command from `go-1.7.6/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric`

```
    make peer
```

or

```
    make
```

getting error

```
    COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder098718235/payload/protoc-gen-go: no such file or directory
```

[Screen shot of terminal. Failed at step 2/5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snZNd.png)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you really have some reason for using v0.6 (which is no longer supported within the Hyperledger Fabric community), I'd suggest you move to the current release - v1.0.X.  You can find the documentation [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/).

And if your goal is to start using Hyperledger Fabric (and not actually contributing the code codebase), there is really no reason to build from source.  We publish Docker images and a series of getting started samples and tutorials - all of which can be found in the documentation link posted above.